# Fotorama - change cursor to custom image of arrow, previous and next

Tags: image, cursor, fotorama

I am trying to change the cursor to a custom image of a "previous" and "next" arrow via CSS but am not having any luck.
I would like for the cursor to change to a left arrow when hovering on the left side, and to a right arrow when hovering on the ride side.
It seems that something is overriding my CSS when I add it in the stylesheet.

```
.leftarrow:hover {cursor: url(leftarrow.png), auto;}
.rightarrow:hover {cursor: url(rightarrow.png), auto;}
```

Is this possible to do via CSS, or do I need some JS for this?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Why css?
you can change it in plugin options ;)

```
$('#fotorama').fotorama({
 arrowPrev: '<img src="/path-to-image/Previous.png" width="30" height="30" >',
 arrowNext: '<img src="/path-to-image/Next.png" width="30" height="30" >'
});
```

Comment: No, this is not possible with the current version.